# Bad words filter if else integration

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there any way to implement if else in the below mentioned badwords filter code so that when user enter any bad word it will give error "your input contains words that are not allowed" rather than replacing the badwords

```
FUNCTION BadWordFilter(&$text, $replace){

$file_array = file('/path/to/badword.txt');


$bads = array();
foreach ($file_array as $word_combo) {
$bads[] = explode(',', $word_combo);
}



IF($replace==1) {                                        //we are replacing
  $remember = $text;

  FOR($i=0;$i<sizeof($bads);$i++) {               //go through each bad word
       $text = EREGI_REPLACE($bads[$i][0],$bads[$i][1],$text); //replace it
  }

  IF($remember!=$text) RETURN 1;                     //if there are any changes, return 1

} ELSE {                                                  //we are just checking

  FOR($i=0;$i<sizeof($bads);$i++) {               //go through each bad word
       IF(EREGI($bads[$i][0],$text)) RETURN 1; //if we find any, return 1
  }     
 }

}

$any = BadWordFilter($qtitle,1); 
$any = BadWordFilter($qtitle,0);
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question? whats wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want a way to tell if the return value of the function indicates that "bad words" were replaced, or found. Given what you currently have, you already know if you're replacing them or not, you just need to add a `return 0;` to the end of your method that will indicate that no replacement has been made or no bad-words have been found.

I have rewritten your sample in a way that should handle this. In the rewrite, I have also changed your usage of [`eregi_replace()`](http://php.net/eregi_replace) and [`eregi()`](https://www.php.net/eregi) with [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) and [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match), respectively. The former two methods are deprecated and should not be used. Also, I have not tested the following, it's only meant as a proof-of-concept:

```
function BadWordFilter(&$text, $replaceWords = false) {
    $file_array = file('/path/to/badword.txt');
    $bads = array();
    foreach ($file_array as $word_combo) $bads[] = explode(',', $word_combo);
    
    if ($replaceWords == true) {
        $original = $text;
        foreach ($bads as $bad) {
            // replace any bad word instance
            $text = str_replace($bad[0], $bad[1], $text);
        }
        // check if bad words have been replaced
        return ($text == $original) ? false : true;
    } else {
        foreach ($bads as $bad) {
            if (strpos($text, $bad[0]) !== false) {
                // found a bad word
                return true;
            }
        }
        // no bad words found
        return false;
    }
}

$error = '';
// replace words:
if (BadWordFilter($qtitle, true)) {
    $error = 'Your input contained bad words and they have been replaced.';
}
// don't replace words:
if (BadWordFilter($qtitle, false)) {
    $error = 'Your input contains words that are not allowed.';
}
```

**UPDATE:** After seeing the sample input text in the "bad words" file, regular expressions aren't necessary. I've replaced the original replacements of `preg_replace()` and `preg_match()` with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) and [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos), respectively.

Comment: If I use preg_replace instead of eregi_replace its giving me error:
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /home/path/to/submit.php on line 32

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /home/path/to/submit.php on line 38

Comment: Line 32:$text = preg_replace($bad[0], $bad[1], $text);
Line38:if (preg_match($bad[0], $text)) {

Comment: and this is how badword.txt looks like
http://tinypaste.com/37d25b17

I think format of badword.txt is a problem ?

Comment: @user1528878 Yeah, regular expressions are pretty sensitive and your input definitely won't mesh as-is. Because you don't have any words/input that actually require regular expressions, you can use `str_replace()` instead: `$text = str_replace($bad[0], $bad[1], $text);`. I'll update the example to match too.

Comment: The updated version is now case sensitive Crap will not be replaced whereas crap will be replaced by ***
and again It only replaces with *** not giving error "Your input contains words that are not allowed."

Comment: The input is taken through $qtitle variable.Is there a way to stop taking input if any bad word is found and the script will give the error "Your input contains words that are not allowed" without replacing
So far Thanks for the great help